# Calculate hypergeometric function

Tags: matlab, integral

i need to calculate the degenerate hypergeometric function of two variables given by integral formula:

[image: my hypergeometric function]

and I used Matlab for taking numerical integral:

```
l =  0.067;
h =  0.933;
n = 1.067;
o = 0.2942;
p = 0.633;
func_F=@(x)(x.^(l-1)).*((1-x).^(n-l-1)).*((1-x.*o).^(-h)).*exp(x.*p);
hyper= quadl(func_F,0,1,'AbsTol',1e-6); % i use 'AbsTol' to avoid warnings
disp(hyper);
```

The result i got is 54.9085, and i know this value is wrong! So please help me to calculate true value of the above integral with singularity at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you have the Gamma functions in your code.  Did you forget them, or did the value you were expecting already compensate for the lack of them?

Also, maybe you can state why "this value is wrong."   Otherwise we are just guessing.

Edit:  one more thing, as per the [Matlab help page on this function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quadl.html), it might be better to use `quadgk`.  See the following quote (near the bottom of the page):

> The quadgk function will integrate functions that are singular at
>   finite endpoints if the singularities are not too strong. For example,
>   it will integrate functions that behave at an endpoint c like log|x-c|
>   or |x-c|p for p >= -1/2. If the function is singular at points inside
>   (a,b), write the integral as a sum of integrals over subintervals with
>   the singular points as endpoints, compute them with quadgk, and add
>   the results.

Bottom line is the the singularities near the endpoints (when your `x` gets near 0 or 1) might cause some problems.

Comment: Yes, i removed the the gamma function coefficient, i just mean the main integral.
I expanded the integral in series form and the value i got is 16.0675, and 54.9085 is too large.